# Not able to perform mean aggregation on group by DataFrame in Panda

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have below dataset

[image]

I want to perform mean operation on 'horsepower' column after doing group by on column 'cylinders' and 'model year' using panda. I am running code in jupyter notebook.

Below is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('auto_mpg.csv')
df.groupby(['cylinders','model year']).agg({'horsepower':'mean'})
```

Basically, I am performing first group by on column 'cylinders' and 'model year' and then performing aggregation operation to get mean value.
I am getting below error:

```
DataError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-105-967f7e0151c3> in <module>
      2 #Creating a DataFrame grouped on cylinders and model_year and finding mean, min and max of horsepower
      3 df = pd.read_csv('auto_mpg.csv')
----> 4 df.groupby(['cylinders','model year']).agg({'horsepower':['mean']})
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    949         func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
    950 
--> 951         result, how = self._aggregate(func, *args, **kwargs)
    952         if how is None:
    953             return result
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
    414 
    415                 try:
--> 416                     result = _agg(arg, _agg_1dim)
    417                 except SpecificationError:
    418 
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg(arg, func)
    381                 result = {}
    382                 for fname, agg_how in arg.items():
--> 383                     result[fname] = func(fname, agg_how)
    384                 return result
    385 
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\base.py in _agg_1dim(name, how, subset)
    365                         "nested dictionary is ambiguous in aggregation"
    366                     )
--> 367                 return colg.aggregate(how)
    368 
    369             def _agg_2dim(how):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    244             # but not the class list / tuple itself.
    245             func = maybe_mangle_lambdas(func)
--> 246             ret = self._aggregate_multiple_funcs(func)
    247             if relabeling:
    248                 ret.columns = columns
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in _aggregate_multiple_funcs(self, arg)
    317                 obj._reset_cache()
    318                 obj._selection = name
--> 319             results[base.OutputKey(label=name, position=idx)] = obj.aggregate(func)
    320 
    321         if any(isinstance(x, DataFrame) for x in results.values()):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\generic.py in aggregate(self, func, engine, engine_kwargs, *args, **kwargs)
    238 
    239         if isinstance(func, str):
--> 240             return getattr(self, func)(*args, **kwargs)
    241 
    242         elif isinstance(func, abc.Iterable):
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in mean(self, numeric_only)
   1391         Name: B, dtype: float64
   1392         """
-> 1393         return self._cython_agg_general(
   1394             "mean",
   1395             alt=lambda x, axis: Series(x).mean(numeric_only=numeric_only),
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py in _cython_agg_general(self, how, alt, numeric_only, min_count)
   1049 
   1050         if len(output) == 0:
-> 1051             raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")
   1052 
   1053         return self._wrap_aggregated_output(output, index=self.grouper.result_index)
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

While I get min and max aggregation on 'horsepower' column successfully.

```
df = pd.read_csv('auto_mpg.csv')
df.groupby(['cylinders','model year']).agg({'horsepower':['min','max']})
```

[image]

Comment: Check data types of horsepower column. It should be any numeric data type.

Comment: Data  type is correct. I am able to get min and max.

Comment: There's `NaNs` in the column. Fill them `df.horsepower.fillna(0)`. You might wanna change the 0 to column average. @Md Firdaus Alam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I loaded the auto-mpg the dataset from https://www.kaggle.com/uciml/autompg-dataset/version/3nd
and managed to replicate the problem.
The root cause is that `horsepower` column is loaded as type `object` with missing values represented as question mark strings (`?`), for example:

```
df[df.horsepower.str.contains("\?")]
```

Pandas doesn't know how to take the mean of question marks, so the solution would be casting the column to float:

```
# Convert non digit strings to NaN
df.loc[~df.horsepower.str.isdigit(), "horsepower"] = np.NaN
# Cast to float
df.horsepower = df.horsepower.astype("float")
# Aggregate
df.groupby(["cylinders", "model year"]).agg({"horsepower": "mean"})
```

Used `pandas==1.1.5` and `numpy==1.19.5`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the data type. I see the root cause error at the bottom of your post:

raise DataError("No numeric types to aggregate")

Answer (score 0):

Put that ‘mean’ into bracket then, if data type is right:

agg({'horsepower': ['mean']})

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
df = pd.read_csv('auto_mpg.csv')
df.groupby(['cylinders','model year']).mean()["horsepower]
```

`df.groupby(['cylinders','model year']).mean()` will give you the mean of each column and then you are selecting the horsepower variable to get the desired columns from the df on which groupby and mean operations were performed.

Comment: What if I want to perform multiple aggregation on column 'horsepower' like:               
 df = pd.read_csv('auto_mpg.csv')
df.groupby(['cylinders','model year']).agg({'horsepower':['min','max','mean']})

Comment: Why will someone compute the mean of all columns to get mean of just one column!